# How do I prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{i\in A}x_{i}$ is divisible by $n$?

Tags: number-theory

The problem is from my friend who sent a message looking for help. I don't think for a long time to solve, so I hope someone can help me to solve it. Thank you

**Question**:

> Given a integer $n$ greater than $1$, suppose that $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ are integers such that none of them is divisible by $n$, and neither is their sum. Prove that there exists at least $n-1$ non-empty subsets $A\subseteq \{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$, such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i\in A}x_{i}$ is divisible by $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to be a modified version of a problem posed in the Baltic Way- competition in 2004. [See here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://www.balticway07.dk/data/ekstra/bw02-06-online-a5.pdf&ei=VT5ZUpfvG6io4gTO0ICIBQ&usg=AFQjCNHlcMpagEdBTIsR0FHG84hRiu5KWg&sig2=4cG2O5cnIjP8AwRNCwG3Iw) and look for problem 04.9.